# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') - using Stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Why isn't map showing up? Been spending the last few days trying to figure out why isn't it recognizing my arrays. My goal is to use stripe to individual put a item into the cart from my shop.html.

The problem is that when I click a product to add to the cart to checkout it shows all the products, including the prices and total, on the stripe session instead of the item I selected.

**server.js**

```
// require("dotenv").config()

// This is your test secret API key.
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_XXXXXXX')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())

const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:4242';

const storeItems = new Map([
   [1, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Black Sweatsuit"}],
   [2, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Grey Sweatsuit"}] ,
   [3, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Red Sweatsuit"}],
   [4, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Blue Sweatsuit"}],
   [5, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Black T-Shirt"}],
   [6, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Blue T-Shirt"}],
   [7, { priceId: 'price_XXXXXX', name: "Purple T-Shirt"}],
])

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      mode: 'payment',
      line_item: req.body.items.map(item => {
        const storeItem = storeItems.get(item.id)
        return {
          price_data: {
            currency:'usd',
            product_data: {
              name: storeItem.name
            },
            unit_amount: storeItem.priceId
          },
          quantity: item.quantity
        }
      }),
      success_url:`${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success.html`,
      cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel.html`,
      automatic_tax: {enabled: true},    
    })
    res.json({ url: session.url})
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message })
  }
})

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

**checkout.js**

```
 const button = document.getElementById("checkout-button")
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      fetch('/create-checkout-session', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          items: [
            { id: 1, quantity: 1 },
            { id: 2, quantity: 1 },
            { id: 3, quantity: 1 },
            { id: 4, quantity: 1 },
            { id: 5, quantity: 1 },
            { id: 6, quantity: 1 },
            { id: 7, quantity: 1 },
          ],
        }),
      })
        .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) return res.json()
        return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
      })
        .then(({ url }) => {
        window.location = url
      })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e.error)
      })

})
```

**terminal**

```
{"error":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"}
```

Comment: What is `req.body.items` when you are attempting to map it?

Comment: Right now, your client-side code sends a JSON to your server with just numbers and nothing else. Your server-side code then adds them all to the Session. You don't seem to "select" one, you just add them all. So that's also part of the issue. And what @mykaf said above too, like the next step is to print the content of your variable to debug what's happening exactly.

Comment: @koopajah could you guys provide an example of what you all are explaining? I'm not sure if I'm understanding.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` and see what's in there?